# Number of pair in array that satisfy Bitwise Equation

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor

I found this problem in a contest. The question is:

You are given an array of `N` non-negative integers *(A1, A2, A3,..., An)* and an integer `M`. Your task is to find the number of unordered pairs of array elements `(X,Y)` that satisfies the following bitwise equation:

> `2 * set_bits(X|Y) = M + set_bits(X ⊕ Y)`

Note:

- `set_bits(n)` represents the number of ones in the binary represenataion of an integer **n**.
- `X|Y` represents the bitwise OR of integer **X** and **Y**.
- `X ⊕ Y` represents the bitwise XOR of integer **X** and **Y**.
- The unordered pair of array elements is pair `(Ai, Aj)` where **1 ≤ i < j ≤ N**.

Print the number of unordered pairs of array elements that satisfy the above bitwise equation.

1. Sample Input 1:
   N=4 M=2
   arr = [3, 0, 4, 5]
   Sample Output: 2
   *2 pairs are (3,0) and (0,5)*
2. Sample Input 2:
   N=8 M=2
   arr = [3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 8]
   Sample Output: 9

Is there any other way except `brute force` to solve this equation?

Comment: Are the array elements bounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with time complexity `O(n)` exists if the time complexity of `set_bits` is `O(1)`.

First, we are going to rephrase the condition (the bitwise equation) a bit. Assume a pair of elements `(X, Y)` is given. Let `c_01` represent the number of digits where X is 0 but Y is 1, `c_10` represent the number digits where X is 1 and Y is 0, and `c_11` represent the number of digits where X and Y are 1. For example, when `X=5` and `Y=1` (X=101, Y=001), `c_01 = 0`, `c_10 = 1`, `c_11 = 1`. Now, the condition can be rewritten as

```
2 * (c_01 + c_10 + c_11) = M + (c_01 + c_10)
```

because `set_bits(X|Y)` is equal to `c_01 + c_10 + c_11` and `set_bits(X^Y)` is equal to `c_01 + c_10`.
We can reorder the equation into

```
c_01 + c_10 + 2*c_11 = M
```

by moving the term on the right to the left side. Now, realize that `set_bits(X) = c_10 + c_11`. Applying this information on the equation we get

```
c_01 + c_11 = M - set_bits(X)
```

Now, also realize that `set_bits(Y) = c_01 + c_11`. The equation becomes

```
set_bits(Y) = M - set_bits(X)
```

or

```
set_bits(X) + set_bits(Y) = M
```

The problem has turned into counting the number of pairs such that the number of set bits in the first element plus the number of set bits in the second element is equal to `M`. This can be done in linear time assuming you can compute `set_bits` in constant time.